# scheduled notification on android studio app. alarmManager.set doesn't work

Tags: android, notifications

that's my code for scheduled notification for my android app, but it does nothing for some reason. Please tell me where is the problem.
Another question: I also made a button which send a notification - just for learning, and for some reason it works only on my samsung s6. When I run the app on the android studio emulator it gives me an error about notification package. Why is that?
Thank a lot!

```
public void setAlarm(View view) {
        Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;

        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)
                getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }
}


public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        createNotification(context, "Time Up", "5 Seconds Has Passed", "Alert");
    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {

        PendingIntent noficitIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setTicker(msgAlert)
                .setContentText(msgText);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(noficitIntent);

        mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is missing important parts. Where is your AlertReceiver instance? Is it registered somewhere else?

Comment: No, this is all the relevant code. Why do I need an instance of AlertReceiver? I checked through lots of examples in the internet and there nothing seems to be missing...

Comment: Per BroadcastReceiver docs: You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with Context.registerReceiver() or statically declare an implementation with the <receiver> tag in your AndroidManifest.xml. That's why I asked you where AlertReceiver is registered. You can't just broadcast an intent and then wait your receiver to be called without registering it previously (either dynamically or statically).

Comment: would you please help me by telling me what exactly I need to add in the manifest?

Comment: Sure, I'm going to put it as an answer, it's better to format code. Hope it helps.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, it seems you just forgot to register your BroadcastReceiver. Per Android docs you will only be able to receive intents on your receiver if you register it first:

> You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with Context.registerReceiver() or statically declare an implementation with the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Since you are sending a broadcast directly to your receiver like that:

```
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
```

There is no point in declaring any `intent-filter` for it, so you just need to add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml (inside `<application>` tag):

```
<receiver android:name="com.your.package.AlertReceiver" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Although the original asker didn't mark this as the accepted answer, I'd like to point out this is the correct solution. Adding that one line to the AndroidManifest.xml finally put an end to a week and a half of head bashing and pointless rounds of emails with a very unhelpful professor. So I just wanted to draw some attention to this. Thank you sir!